# If I take an XRD image of a single cubic unit cell, would the diffraction pattern simply be its reciprocal lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, diffraction, x-ray-crystallography

I've seen the rings from powder diffraction images, and I read that each line is made up of a lot of dots, I was wondering if these dots are reciprocal lattice points of the structure. And if we weren't looking at a powder but just a 2D hexagonal lattice, then the xrd pattern would simply be its reciprocal lattice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked a total of three questions, so I'll answer each one in turn. But first, how much do you already know about what you see when light diffracts from an object? I assume you're aware of the fact that the reciprocal lattice is the Fourier transform of the crystal?

In general, there is a direct analogy between x-ray diffraction and directional phased-array radio broadcasting, and which is very helpful in understanding x-ray diffraction. If you'd like, I can explain this analogy in another post, but the end result is that if you blast an object with x-rays with wavevector ${\bf k}$, the object will re-emit that light in all directions, and the intensity of that emitted light as a function of angle is proportional to

$$F({\bf \Omega}+{\bf k})$$

where $F$ is the Fourier transform of the object's density function $f$, and ${\bf \Omega}={\hat n}|{\bf k}|$ where ${\hat n}$ is the unit vector pointing out of the crystal and in the direction of emission.

As a result, a crystal's x-ray diffraction pattern is determined by the Fourier transform of it's underlying lattice, ie, the reciprocal lattice.

Now assume you have an imaging sphere (ie, a sphere whose interior surface is covered by photographic film), you place the crystal in the center, you fire x-rays in through a pinhole, and they strike the crystal and diffract, striking the film on the walls and forming an image. What will the image look like? Looking at the expression ${\bf \Omega}+{\bf k}$, you'll note that as ${\bf \Omega}$ is varied in all directions, it traces out the surface of a bubble in reciprocal space whose surface touches the origin, whose radius is $|{\bf k}|$, and whose center is located at ${\bf k}$.

This bubble is something called the "Ewald bubble". The most important intuition is this:

- The image recorded on the photographic film after bombardment is a photograph of the Ewald bubble in reciprocal space.

Take a moment to think about that and let it sink in. What it's saying is that x-ray diffraction hands us a picture of the crystal in Fourier-transform space. (However, note that the formula $I({\bf \Omega})\propto F({\bf \Omega}+{\bf k})$ is perfectly general, and does not assume that the object $f$ is a crystal, is periodic, or anything else. So it works for non-periodic structures like a single unit cell as well.)

We can get a complete reconstruction of the reciprocal lattice by rotating the crystal while imaging. Applying various rotations matrices $R(\theta,\phi)$ to the crystal (which is equivalent to sending in the x-rays at different directions), we find that the set of images $S$ obtained is
$$S=\{F({\hat n}|{\bf k}|+R(\theta,\phi){\bf k}),{\hat n}\in\mbox{all directions},\theta\in[0,\pi],\phi\in[0,2\pi]  \}$$
$$=\{F({\bf r}),|{\bf r}|\leq2|{\bf k}| \}.$$
The last equality may take a bit of visualization, but once you see it it's pretty obvious; essentially you just swing around the Ewald bubble in all directions while keeping it's surface attached to the origin, which traces out a solid sphere of radius $2|{\bf k}|$. The important intuition is this:

- Using x-rays with inverse wavelength $|{\bf k}|$, you can reconstruct the object in Fourier transform space out to a radius of $2|{\bf k}|$.

Now to finally try to answer your questions:

1. If I take an XRD image of a single cubic unit cell, would the diffraction pattern simply be its reciprocal lattice?

No. It would be the Ewald bubble image of the Fourier transform of the density function of that single unit cell. The reciprocal lattice is the Fourier transform of the density function of the periodically-repeated unit cells, not just one cell. The FT of a single cell would be something much blurrier, and obviously in real life it'd be super hard to mechanically obtain a single unit cell of a crystal, let alone image it.

1. I was wondering if these dots are reciprocal lattice points of the structure.

Yes, sort of. Applying the formula $I({\bf \Omega})\propto F({\bf \Omega}+{\bf k})$ to a powder can be done by imagining that the powder is actually millions of little crystals, all oriented randomly. Since rotation commutes with Fourier-transformation, this yields a reciprocal-space function for the powder of
$$F_R({\bf r})=\int_{SO(3)} F(R(\chi)\cdot {\bf r})d\chi$$
where the integral is over all the Euler angles. It should be geometrically obvious that this function is just the reciprocal space after being smeared out by rotations, in a similar manner as to that observed when amateur astronomers photograph the night sky using timed-exposure film. As a result, the powder reciprocal space is radially symmetric about the origin, and the Ewald bubble intersects the smeared-out reciprocal lattice points to generate rings on the surface of the bubble. These surface rings manifests in real life space as conical emission patterns, as shown in this diagram:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/HEX-2D-diffraction.png

1. And if we weren't looking at a powder but just a 2D hexagonal lattice, then the xrd pattern would simply be its reciprocal lattice?

Yes. Or at least, it would be the image of the Ewald bubble of radius $|{\bf k}|$ in reciprocal lattice space.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer... but can you please tell us more about why the x-ray diffracted data should be in the reciprocal space?!!

Comment: the one you mentioned in the first paragraph that you could explain more...